# Proof $f’’(x)\ge 0$ and $f$ continuous implies midpoint convex

Tags: real-analysis

I have found many proofs for the converse but none for $f$ continuous and 
$f’’(x)\ge 0  \Rightarrow $ midpoint convex and I am struggling to find a way to prove in this direction

Comment: You can simply take $t=1/2$ in the [definition of convexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Definition) to deduce that a convex function is also midpoint convex.

Comment: Sorry, I got the definition of convex mixed with second derivative, can you still prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, of course assuming that $f$ is continuous is redundant: If $f''(x)$ *exists* for every $x$ then $f$ is certainly continuous. In fact $f'$ is differentiable, hence continuous.

And $f''\ge0$ implies that $f'$ is non-decreasing. And now you're done. **For example**, MVT shows that there exist $a\in(0,1)$ and $b\in(-1,0)$ such that
$$(f(-1)+f(1))-2f(0)=(f(1)-f(0))-(f(0)-f(-1))=f'(a)-f'(b)\ge0,$$since  $a\ge b$.